# Why Neo4J docker authentication doesn't work

Tags: docker, authentication, neo4j, docker-compose

I want to run a Neo4J instance through docker using a docker-compose.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  neo4j:
    container_name: neo4j-lab
    image: neo4j:latest
    environment:
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=2G
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_maxSize=4G
      - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initialSize=512M
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - neo4j_data:/data
      - neo4j_conf:/conf
      - ./import:/import
volumes:
  neo4j_data:
  neo4j_conf:
```

Running the following with `docker-compose up` is perfectly fine, and I can reach the login screen.

But when I set the credentials, I get the following error on my container logs : **Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.** whereas I am sure that I fill with right credentials (the ones used in my docker-compose file)

Furthermore,

- when I set `NEO4J_AUTH` to `none`, then no credentials have been asked.
- when I set it to `neo4j/neo4j` it said that I can't use the default password

According the documentation, this is perfectly fine :

> By default Neo4j requires authentication and requires you to login with neo4j/neo4j at the first connection and set a new password. **You can set the password for the Docker container directly by specifying --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password in your run directive. Alternatively, you can disable authentication by specifying --env NEO4J_AUTH=none instead.**

Do you have any idea of what's going on ?

Hope you could help me to solve this !

**EDIT**

Docker logs output :

```
neo4j-lab | 2019-03-13 23:02:32.378+0000 INFO  Starting...
neo4j-lab | 2019-03-13 23:02:37.796+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
neo4j-lab | 2019-03-13 23:02:41.102+0000 INFO  Started.
neo4j-lab | 2019-03-13 23:02:43.935+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
neo4j-lab | 2019-03-13 23:02:56.105+0000 WARN  The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
```

**EDIT 2 :**

It seems that deleting the volume associated first works. The password is now changed.

However, if I `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up` whereas I change the password in my `docker-compose file` then the issue reappears.

So I think that when we change the password through docker-compose **more than once** while a volume exists, we need to remove the `auth` file presents in the volumes.

To do that :

```
docker volume inspect <volume_name>
```

You should get something like that :

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-03-14T11:17:08+01:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "neo4j",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "neo4j_data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/data/docker/volumes/neo4j_neo4j_data/_data",
        "Name": "neo4j_neo4j_data",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

This is obviously different if you named your container and your volumes not like me (neo4j, neo4j_data).

The important part is the **Mountpoint** which locates the volume.

In this volume, you can delete the `auth` file which is in `dbms` directory.

Then restart your docker and everything should be fine.

Comment: what is the docker logs output ?

Comment: I put my docker logs output in original message ;)

Comment: it seems like started the container with old data where the password was not `changeme`

Comment: I have tested same settings and it works as expected

Comment: This is the problem.. :( I didn't mention it, but I ran these docker-compose file on two different machine, and it worked on one of them...

Comment: I finally find the reason of my problem, I let you see my edit 2. :)

Comment: Glad you did it!.  That's why to told you to remove the old data :D because the volume will keep the old password

Comment: I think the problem is not only the password because I didn't change it. But I pull the latest image yesterday and the volume was associated to an older version, I don't know if this kind of situation can cause this kind of issue... But now it works !

Comment: @Dralucas your post just ended 6 hours of head banging because my password wasn't accepted. I've not seen anything in the neo docs that mentions what you explained above. Thank you so much!

Comment: I was hoping this would fix things for me, but no.   https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/issues/238

Answer (score 17):

Neo4j docker developer here.

The reason this is happening is that the `NEO4J_AUTH` environment variable doesn't set the database password, it sets the **INITIAL** password only.

If you're mounting a data volume with an existing database inside, then `NEO4J_AUTH` has no effect because that database already has a password. It sounds like that's what you're experiencing here.

The documentation around this feature was not great and I've updated it! See: [Neo4j docker authentication documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/introduction/#docker-auth)

Comment: How does one reset the password, by modifying the auth file after the initial password is set? Some details on this in the docs would be great @jenny

Comment: Is there a way to stop the requirement to change the password on first logon when running in docker?

Answer (score 2):

#### define Neo4j password with docker-compose

```
neo4j:
   image: 'neo4j:4.1'
   environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: 'neo4j/your_password'
   ports:
      - "7474:7474"
   volumes:
      ...
```

Comment: The issue appears when there is a password change inside the container. Providing password through docker-compose makes it a static one.

Comment: this is actually where the above problem started for me...